# WSO2 IS does not work after upgrade to 5.11.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have upgraded wso2 server from wso2 IS 5.10.0 to IS 5.11.0. I understand that there has been change in CORS, I have removed CORS filter from web.xml and added configuration to deployment.toml. I still see below two errors in logs of wso2.

1. `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.service.handler.AuthorizationHandler} - Error occurred while trying to authorize, Operation is not supported.`
2. `ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve} - CORS management service error when intercepting an HTTP request. org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.mgt.core.exception.CORSManagementServiceServerException`

Please guide me how to fix this errors

Comment: have you refered https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-what-has-changed/#configuring-cors

Comment: yes, i did follow the configuration changes accordingly

Comment: Is this the only error log that is there? is their any stacktrace with a caused by?

Comment: I somehow managed to get rid of this error by adding tables to mysql db:  IDN_CONFIG_TYPE, IDN_CONFIG_RESOURCE, IDN_CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE and IDN_CONFIG_FILE tables

Comment: which means you had a error in your stacktrace saying configuration management feature is not enabled am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. the errors says "caused because configuration is not enabled". Thanks